Iis hosted website has 1 sec added for each request
After migrating from net.framework to net6 we have started seeing 1 sec. added to each web request for iis hosted website. We have two servers (I believe they are VMs), one has the issue, another hasn't.
Code base is the same, both servers has the same windows (Windows Server 2019 Standard 1809) and IIS (10.0.17763.1).
I have created simple console app (net6), which sends http request (using HttpClient) to a default IIS website. This app shows 1 sec. delay for affected server and doesn't show any delay on other server.
I've tried to create HttpClient differently (using default constructor, using HttpClientHandler, using SoketsHttpHandler, setting UseProxy = false and many more) but result is the same.
If I compile this app for net4.8 it doesn't have any delay on affected server.
I've created another owin hosted app, and if I send a request to it - no delays.
So it should be something connected with IIS and difference in HttpClient in net48 and net6.
It might be also connected with some security tools installed on server, but nothin has changed when security team disabled them.

There are IIS Failed Request Tracing and ASP.NET Core module logging that can give you more insights into where the time was spent on the server side. But "If I compile this app for net4.8 it doesn't have any delay on affected server" is ambiguous. Did you mean this is a client side issue? I don't think the troubleshooting is thorough so far.

You also mentioned that the problem only occurs in one of the servers. Is there any custom module configuration? Are the requests tested synchronous or asynchronous? Multiple requests or a single request? and so on. And as already mentioned, trying to collect some logs or performance monitoring information should help locate the cause of the problem.
